# how is http live streaming sync between sender and receiver done?

Tags: vlc, http-live-streaming, libavcodec

Http live streaming is a sliding window of a video source. what happens if the sender is slightly faster or slower than the receiver? The receiver will hit one end of the sliding window. Does anybody know how this gets prevented? As sender I use a C++ test program that uses libavcodec and as receiver I use VLC.

Answer (score 0):

Faster is not going to be problem, is it?  The frame buffer queue gets full, the TCP reader gets blocked, the TCP stack bufers get full, the TCP stack slides the window closed and comms stops until frames are consumed by the renderer.

Slower - your choice.  When all the TCP stack buffers and internal frame buffer queue has run down to zero, you could negotiate with the server for a lower resolution or lower frame rate.

Comment: i mean if the nominal framerate is 25 fps and the receiver displays at 24,9 fps then it eventually will have to skip a whole segment as the next segment it want to show already has disappeared from the playlist. vlc seems to stop in this case.